# App Engine App works on development server but not on the the hosted server

Tags: google-app-engine

i've just developed, tested and deployed my Java App Engine App on the App Engine hosted platform. But to my dismay, while the local version works on the development server without bugs, when deployed, the App fails miserably with a 500 Server Error. When i look into the logs for the error, i can see a "java.lang.NullPointerException". But the local and hosted datastore entities and data are similar.

Has anyone encountered this problem? What should i do. Thanks.

Comment: Is there more detail in the stacktrace around the null pointer exception? Chances are you are expecting some data to be there that isn't. I suggest you wipe you local datastore clean and see if the problem happens locally.

Comment: Rob thanks, i discovered the problem. I was passing the wrong Entity kind which didn't exist, hence the NullPointer Exception on the results returned. However, i expected this error to be shown on the development environment first, but everything worked perfectly!!